# How to use MethodInvoder with parameters and return value

Tags: c#, delegates

We need to calculate the function execution time in every function. The origin code was like:

```
private void Cal1() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    Console.WriteLine("This is method");
    Console.WriteLine("Bye");
}
```

Apparently, no one likes to add two same lines at  begin and end of the function.

Then I try to  use delegate to make our life easier...

```
private void Execute(MethodInvoker act)
{ 
    string name = act.GetMethodInfo().ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("Start "+ name);
    act();
    Console.WriteLine("Bye");
}

private void Cal1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is method");
}
```

Some one could call like this....

```
Execute(Cal1);
```

In this scenario, how do handle the function with return value and parameters?

Comment: A lambda might work, then the delegate has no parameters but the values are captured in the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need proxy class. I think you must look into these pages.

https://www.postsharp.net/

http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/